# jQuery hide/fadeIn isn't smooth

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am having a weird issue where hide & fadeIn isn't smooth.
I am using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function()
    {
        $.fn.scrollToTop=function(){
            $("#toTop").hide().removeAttr("href");
            if($(window).scrollTop()!="0"){
                $(this).fadeIn("slow")
            }
            var scrollDiv=$(this);
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop()=="0"){
                    $(scrollDiv).fadeOut("slow")
                }else{
                    $(scrollDiv).fadeIn("slow")
                }
            });
            $(this).click(function(){
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},"slow");
            });
        }
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#toTop, #toFavourites").scrollToTop();
    });

});
```

The same exact code is running on http://adriantomic.se/development/scroll-to-the-top-with-jquery/ where I took it from.
When scrolling down and up, the label gradually appears and disappears smoothly.

However, when I am using the same exact code on my own dev site, the label animation (appearance and disappearance) isn't smooth at all.

Any idea what causes this issue and how to fix it?

Thanks

P.S. Just to clarify, I mean this label: 
[image]

Comment: The scroll performance isn't too bad for me however it may be caused by a number of things such as what content is on your page. Given you have an embedded Google map and also an animated navigation bar, either of these may affect scroll performance. Have you tried removing one of these from the page to see if this improves performance? If it does, then it's clear where the problem is and you can dig deeper into the cause.

Comment: Which part that is acting strange again? The fadeIn of `#toTop`?

Comment: @ timothyclifford Thanks, but I am referring to the label appearance/disappearance and the hide/fadeIn functions, not the scroll performance.

Comment: @choz yes, that's right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit lies in your `main.css` line `119` which states:

```
a {
    color: #656565;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

Remove the `transition`, and try your `fadeOut` again. It will be smooth after.

Comment: choz, you, my friend, are a genius! Thanks for catching that! :)